# Why can't I get the any 3D plots output with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter

I am unable to get the output I expect, but there is no error either. Can you help me understanding why?

I am new to numpy so I have very little idea.

```
# import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np                       



# initialising arrays
n=100
r1=np.linspace(0,2,n)                    
r2=np.linspace(0,2,n)
p1=np.linspace(0,1,n)
time_avg=np.empty(shape=(0,n**2))
exp_avg=np.empty(shape=(0,n**2))
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

#calculating two things-time avgerage and expected average,plot accordingly
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        for k in range(0,n):
            t=np.sqrt(r1[i]*r2[j])
            time_avg=np.append(time_avg,t)               
            e=(r1[i]*p1[k]+r2[j]*(1-p1[k]))               
            exp_avg=np.append(exp_avg,e)
            #conditions for plotting
            if time_avg[-1]==exp_avg[-1]:                      
                ax1.scatter(r1[i],r2[j],p1[k],color='k',marker='o')
            if time_avg[-1]>exp_avg[-1]:
                ax1.scatter(r1[i],r2[j],p1[k],color='r',marker='o')
            if time_avg[-1]<exp_avg[-1]:
                ax1.scatter(r1[i],r2[j],p1[k],color='b',marker='o')
#plotting 
ax1.set_xlabel('r1')
ax1.set_ylabel('r2')
ax1.set_label('p1')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure what your problem is without some more details into your environment, package versions, as well as what you're trying to accomplish.

Without knowing more, I see two possible problems with your code:

- You're code runs fine but your environment isn't set up to display the graph properly.
- You're code runs fine but it's taking a long time to run.

My guess is that you're code works "fine," it's just taking an exceedingly long time to run. For instance, here's a [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IndeliblePrivateProperties#main.py) that does in fact produce a graph (note that the variable `n` has been set to `10` instead of `100`).

Without getting too technical, you're code is quite computationally complex (O(n^3)). Without any more details about the environment the code is running in, I think it's somewhat reasonable to assume that your code is just *taking its sweet time*.

Perhaps a good follow up to this is to check that your code does in fact finish and that when it does, it does in fact display an empty graph.

Comment: hi , so my code is running but requiring a lot of time to run. is there any way to optimise it